# Как использовать новые версии GLSL на mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, mac

Пишу приложение на OpenGL. Удалось создать контекст версии 4.1. Но шейдеры поддерживаются только версии 150. При попытке использования любой другой версии возникает ошибка
*ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.
ERROR: Compiled fragment shader was corrupt.*
Мне нужна версия 320 и новее. Почему шейдеры версии 150 компилируются при использовании OpenGL 4.1? Разве нужна не 410 версия?

Xcode 10.3, macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, MacBook Pro 13 2018 iris graphics plus 655.
Пишу на c++

Код шейдеров:

**main.glslv**

```
#version 150 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 v_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 v_light;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 v_color;

out vec4 a_color;
out vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projview;

void main(){
    vec4 position = projview * model * vec4(v_position, 1.0);
    a_color = vec4(v_light.r,v_light.g,v_light.b,1.0f);
    a_texCoord = v_texCoord;
    a_color.rgb += v_light.a;
    a_color.rgb *= 1.0-position.z*0.0025;
    //a_color.rgb = pow(a_color.rgb, vec3(1.0/0.7));
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

**main.glslf**

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 a_color;
in vec2 a_texCoord;
out vec4 f_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture0;

void main(){
    vec4 tex_color = texture(u_texture0, a_texCoord);
    if (tex_color.a < 0.5)
    discard;
    f_color = a_color * tex_color;
}
```

Участок кода с инициализацией GLFW

**Window.cpp**

```
int Window::initialize(int width, int height, const char* title){
if(!glfwInit()){
    std::cerr << "Error: failed init glfw" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

//print glfw errors
glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);

if (window == nullptr){
    std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW Window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 2);


#ifdef __APPLE__
    std::cout << "This is Mac" << std::endl;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

#endif
    //OpenGL version
    unsigned int major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
    unsigned int minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);

    std::cerr << "OpenGL shader version: " << major << "." << minor << std::endl; //4.1

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    std::cerr << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl; //4.1 INTEL-12.10.12


    glViewport(0,0, width, height);

    Window::width = width;
    Window::height = height;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если следовать официальной политике яблочной компании, то opengl использовать не следует, так как эта технология объявлена устаревшей. см https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-mojave-10_14-release-notes

Comment: предлагаю объявить продукты Apple устаревшими:)